# Logic and Proof given $P \to (Q \lor R); Q \to S; R \to S$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Logic and Proof given $P \to (Q \lor R); Q \to S; R \to S$

I have spend quite a bit of time on this but I am not too sure how to proceed next.

Any advice on how to complete this proof please?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean AND or OR? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols - AND looks like an A

Comment: So far you have deduced $Q \vee R$. Use the $\vee$-elimination, to get the two cases: $Q$ and $R$. In both you can use the $\Rightarrow$-elimiation on $2.$ and $3.$ to conclude that $S$. Then the $\Rightarrow$-introduction finishes the proof.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am familiar with it. I am fairly new to proof and logic so when the sentences are more complex I tend to find myself confused as to what to tackle next. I will need to keep practicing.

Comment: @RayX thanks, this makes sense. I will apply this logic and see what the outcome is! Appreciate it.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I meant or in this instance. ∨

Comment: Alternatively, you could go contrapositive: The assumptions then read $$(\lnot Q \land \lnot R) \to \lnot P\\ \lnot S \to \lnot Q\\ \lnot S \to \lnot R$$ and you want to prove $\lnot S \to \lnot P$, which follows quite easily from first applying (2) and (3), and then applying (1).

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. This is very useful... Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a Disjunctive Elimination, rather you want to do Case Analysis.

$$\dfrac{\substack{\displaystyle\phi\to\rho\\\displaystyle\psi\to\rho\\\displaystyle\phi\vee\psi}}{\rho}$$

$\begin{array}{l|l} 5. & Q\vee R \\ & \begin{array}{l|l}6. & \text{if }Q \\ 7. & Q\to S \\ \hline 8. & S \end{array} \\ & \begin{array}{l|l} 9. & \text{if } R \\ 10. & R\to S \\\hline 11. & S \end{array} \\ \hline 12.& S \end{array}$

Comment: So this is somewhat similar to the concept of transitivity in a sense?

Comment: No.  That would be $\dfrac{\substack{\displaystyle\phi\to\psi\\\displaystyle\psi\to\rho}}{\phi\to\rho}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! That makes sense.